# A table with frequency and percentage in R

Tags: r

I have this vector and its frequency table:

```
outcome <- c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
table(outcome)
```

Is it possible to have a table with frequency and percentage (in base R)? This should be the expected output:

```
0    1
5    9
0.36 0.64
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prop.table` :

```
out <- table(outcome)
rbind(out, prop.table(out))

#       0     1
#out 5.000 9.000
#    0.357 0.643
```

Or :

```
rbind(out, out/sum(out))
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak Shah, thank you! You know I tried to do it with a one liner `rbind(table(outcome),prop.table(table(outcome))` but it didn't gave me the same results that I needed.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in that apart from a closing bracket missing. `rbind(table(outcome),prop.table(table(outcome)))` gives the same numbers.

Comment: You're right, there was a missing bracket! I realized that mistake! Thank you!